# printing Problem Through Crystalreport Viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm trying to print a report or export it to pdf file. The CrystalReportViewer binding is ok, but, when I click the Print Button of the NAV, nothing happens, could you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: What version of CrystalReportViewer are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your printer setup in CRV.  Does it have any printers?
It sounds like you have no printers in the setup.